# Issue with Character.getNumericValue()

Tags: java

I'm down to this code:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    var[0]=line;
    splitArray = var[0].toCharArray();
    int j=0;

    for (int i=0; i<sArray.length; i++) {
        if (splitArray[i] != ',' && splitArray[i] != ' ') {
            p[j] = Character.getNumericValue(sArray[i]);
            j++;
        }

        columns = p[0];
        rows = p[1];
    }

    break;
}
```

The problem is that if rows (p[1]) is a two-digit number, 11 for example,
as rows I get the value 1, as the first digit of 11. What can I do to overcome this problem?

Is there some other function I could use, or do I have to do custom "if" loops?

I give as an input a *.txt file.

Assume that the text is 9,11 (9 is for columns and 11 for rows). When I run the code, at columns goes the number 9 normally. But when it comes to the rows (number 11), the p[1] value, is 1 and not 11, because it writes only the first of the two digits.

Comment: Why not use the basic casting `int a = (int) charValue`

Comment: You need to tell us what you want to accomplish. Do you want to read a list of numbers from user input?

Comment: edited. I hope you understand.

Comment: @ares I think the value intended is the digit's numerical value rather than its unicode value.

Answer (score 1):

try using `var[0].split("[, ]")` This will generate strings instead of individual characters, which you can then parse to get them to a numeric type.

Comment: thanks!
but var[] array is type char.
if i make it String, i can't get "getNumericValue".

Comment: Don't use getNumericValue then, use something like Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. You look at only one character at a time, and so, you can only get the value of one digit. Suppose your line is `9,11` as in your example. This would be the array you'll get in `splitArray`:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 9 │ , │ 1 │ 1 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
  0   1   2   3
```

Now, within the loop, at first your `i` is 0, and your `j` is 0, and so your digit is `'9'`, and it will put 9 in `p[0]`, and set `j` to 1.

Then you put `9` into `columns` and `0` (which I assume is the initial value of `p[1]`) into `rows`.

Next, your `i` is 1.

The next character is the `','`. This is skipped, but still, you put values into `columns` and `rows` - the same values as before.

Next, your `i` is 2.

As you can see, `splitArray[2]` is `'1'`. So you get its numerical value and put it into `p[j]`. `j` is currently `1`. So `p[1]` gets `1`. And **the value of `j` is set to 2**

Again, you put the value of `p[0]` (which is still 9) into `columns`, but now the value of `p[1]` has changed, so you put `1` into `rows`.

Next, your `i` is `3`.

The value of `splitArray[3]` is `'1'` - it's the second `'1'` of the `11`. So you get its numerical value - 1 - and put it into `p[j]`. But `j` is now `2`. So the value of `p[2]` becomes `1`. But you never use that value.

Again, you put the value of `p[0]` (which is still 9) into `columns`, and you put the value of `p[1]` (which is still 1, since the previous iteration) into `rows`.

Next, your `i` exceeds the limit and you finish your loop.

So you see, you have problems in your logic:

- You expected `Character.getNumericValue()` to somehow get the whole "11" and convert it. But it only looks at one character.
- If you use it, you have to do your own calculation (multiply existing number by 10, add current digit's value. So if we had "1" in `p[1]`, you need to do something like `p[1] = p[1]*10 + Character.getNumericValue(splitArray[i])`). This means you have to change your logic to remember if you have already started parsing the current number. This sort of logic is called "a state machine".
- In addition, putting the values in `columns` and `rows` *within* your loop is wrong. As you could see, you were assigning them again and again in each step. Either you assign directly to `columns` and `rows`, and avoid using `p` altogether, or you assign to `columns` and `rows` after you finish parsing and have the correct values in `p[0]` and `p[1]`.

Now, doing a state machine is a good thing in certain circumstances, but there are better ways to split strings and parse numbers. You can use the venerable [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) as the other answer told you.

You then get string parts of your original string. And then you can parse them into numbers using [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Comment: thanks, but my arrays are like [a,b, c]..so what do I have to write in the parenthesis?

Comment: Did you read the documentation behind the links that I gave you?